# Scala - Spark Dataframe - Convert rows to Map variable

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Spark Dataframe

```
Level    Hierarchy   Code
--------------------------
Level1  Hier1        1
Level1  Hier2        2
Level1  Hier3        3
Level1  Hier4        4
Level1  Hier5        5
Level2  Hier1        1
Level2  Hier2        2
Level2  Hier3        3
```

I need to convert this to a Map variable like Map[String, Map[Int, String]]

i.e.

```
Map["Level1", Map[1->"Hier1", 2->"Hier2", 3->"Hier3", 4->"Hier4", 5->"Hier5"]]
Map["Level2", Map[1->"Hier1", 2->"Hier2", 3->"Hier3"]]
```

Please suggest a suitable approach to achieve this functionality.

My attempt. It works, but ugly

```
val level_code_df =master_df.select("Level","Hierarchy","Code").distinct()
val hierarchy_names = level_code_df.select("Level").distinct().collect()
val hierarchy_size = hierarchy_names.size
var hierarchyMap : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]] =  scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]]()      
for(i <- 0 to hierarchy_size.toInt-1)    
println("names:"+hierarchy_names(i)(0))
val name = hierarchy_names(i)(0).toString()
val code_level_map = level_code_df.rdd.map{row => {
if(name.equals(row.getAs[String]("Level"))){
Map(row.getAs[String]("Code").toInt -> row.getAs[String]("Hierarchy"))
 } else 
 Map[Int, String]()
  }}.reduce(_++_)

  hierarchyMap = hierarchyMap + (name -> (collection.mutable.Map() ++ code_level_map))     
  }           

   }
```

Comment: Hi, I added my code in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `dataframe.groupByKey("level")` followeed by `mapGroups`. Don't forget also to include kryo map encoder:

```
case class Data(level: String, hierarhy: String, code: Int)
val data = Seq(
Data("Level1","Hier1",1),
Data("Level1","Hier2",2),
Data("Level1","Hier3",3),
Data("Level1","Hier4",4),
Data("Level1","Hier5",5),
Data("Level2","Hier1",1),
Data("Level2","Hier2",2),
Data("Level2","Hier3",3)).toDS
implicit val mapEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Map[String, Map[Int, String]]]
```

Spark 2.0+ :

```
data.groupByKey(_.level).mapGroups{ 
    case (level, values) => Map(level -> values.map(v => (v.code, v.hierarhy)).toMap) 
}.collect() 
//Array[Map[String,Map[Int,String]]] = Array(Map(Level1 -> Map(5 -> Hier5, 1 -> Hier1, 2 -> Hier2, 3 -> Hier3, 4 -> Hier4)), Map(Level2 -> Map(1 -> Hier1, 2 -> Hier2, 3 -> Hier3)))
```

Spark 1.6+:

```
data.rdd.groupBy(_.level).map{
  case (level, values) => Map(level -> values.map(v => (v.code, v.hierarhy)).toMap)
}.collect()
//Array[Map[String,Map[Int,String]]] = Array(Map(Level2 -> Map(1 -> Hier1, 2 -> Hier2, 3 -> Hier3)), Map(Level1 -> Map(5 -> Hier5, 1 -> Hier1, 2 -> Hier2, 3 -> Hier3, 4 -> Hier4)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hope your code corresponds to Spark 2.0+. Will this code work in Spark 1.6

Comment: Updated answer for spark-1.6. Almost the same, just need to convert to rdd

Answer (score 0):

@prudenko's answer is probably the most concise - and should work with Spark 1.6 or later. But - if you're looking for a solution that stays with **DataFrames** API (and not *Datasets*), here's one using a simple UDF:

```
val mapCombiner = udf[Map[Int, String], mutable.WrappedArray[Map[Int, String]]] {_.reduce(_ ++ _)}

val result: Map[String, Map[Int, String]] = df
  .groupBy("Level")
  .agg(collect_list(map($"Code", $"Hierarchy")) as "Maps")
  .select($"Level", mapCombiner($"Maps") as "Combined")
  .rdd.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("Level"), r.getAs[Map[Int, String]]("Combined")))
  .collectAsMap()
```

**NOTICE** that this will perform badly (or OOM) if there might by thousands of different values for a single key (value of `Level`), but since you're collecting this all into driver memory anyway, this probably won't be an issue or your requirement won't work regardless.